# Select two conditions for different panels to then decide two values to select the users game

Tags: java, button, label, panel

I need to select two values from two of my frames (Key and Level) to decide what level of test the user will be completing that will then update the label on the start panel to say if the user has selected anything and what they have selected.

I have used window builder in eclipse to help my do this but when i click the button where i have set the value it doesn't change on the label and the label saying if the user can start of not doesn't change

here is my code..(I know its probably really messy im new to all this):

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame;
    int key = 0;
    int level=0;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Test window = new Test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JPanel Home = new JPanel();
        Home.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 266);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Home);

        JPanel SelectKey = new JPanel();
        SelectKey.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 266);
        frame.getContentPane().add(SelectKey);

        JPanel SelectLevel = new JPanel();
        SelectLevel.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 266);
        frame.getContentPane().add(SelectLevel);
        SelectLevel.setLayout(null);

        JPanel Start = new JPanel();
        Start.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 266);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Start);
        Start.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnHome = new JButton("Home");
        btnHome.setBounds(169, 141, 100, 29);
        btnHome.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home.setVisible(true);
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        Home.setLayout(null);
        Home.add(btnHome);

        JButton btnSelectKey = new JButton("Select Key");
        btnSelectKey.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home.setVisible(false);
                SelectKey.setVisible(true);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnSelectKey.setBounds(159, 67, 117, 29);
        Home.add(btnSelectKey);

        JButton btnSelectLevel = new JButton("Select Level");
        btnSelectLevel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(true);
                Home.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnSelectLevel.setBounds(159, 37, 117, 29);
        Home.add(btnSelectLevel);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Home.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
        btnStart.setBounds(159, 92, 117, 29);
        Home.add(btnStart);

        JLabel lblHome = new JLabel("Home");
        lblHome.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblHome.setBounds(197, 18, 61, 16);
        Home.add(lblHome);


        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Home");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(169, 185, 100, 29);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home.setVisible(true);
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);

            }
        });
        SelectKey.setLayout(null);
        SelectKey.add(btnNewButton);

        JButton btnKeyA = new JButton("Key A");
        btnKeyA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                key = 1;
                System.out.print(key);
            }
        });
        btnKeyA.setBounds(157, 44, 117, 29);
        SelectKey.add(btnKeyA);

        JButton btnKeyB = new JButton("Key B");
        btnKeyB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                key = 2;
                System.out.print(key);
            }
        });
        btnKeyB.setBounds(157, 90, 117, 29);
        SelectKey.add(btnKeyB);

        JButton btnKeyC = new JButton("Key C");
        btnKeyC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                key = 3;
                System.out.print(key);
            }

        });
        btnKeyC.setBounds(157, 129, 117, 29);
        SelectKey.add(btnKeyC);

        JLabel lblSelectKey = new JLabel("Select Key");
        lblSelectKey.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblSelectKey.setBounds(168, 19, 117, 23);
        SelectKey.add(lblSelectKey);


        JButton btnBeginnner = new JButton("Beginnner");
        btnBeginnner.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                level = 1;
                System.out.print(level);
            }
        });
        btnBeginnner.setBounds(158, 67, 117, 29);
        SelectLevel.add(btnBeginnner);

        JButton btnIntermediate = new JButton("Intermediate");
        btnIntermediate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                level=2;
                System.out.print(level);
            }
        });
        btnIntermediate.setBounds(158, 113, 117, 29);
        SelectLevel.add(btnIntermediate);

        JButton btnAdvanced = new JButton("Advanced");
        btnAdvanced.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                level = 3;
                System.out.print(level);
            }
        });
        btnAdvanced.setBounds(158, 166, 117, 29);
        SelectLevel.add(btnAdvanced);

        JButton btnHome_1 = new JButton("Home");
        btnHome_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home.setVisible(true);
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnHome_1.setBounds(158, 207, 117, 29);
        SelectLevel.add(btnHome_1);

        JLabel lblSelectLevel = new JLabel("Select Level");
        lblSelectLevel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblSelectLevel.setBounds(162, 19, 158, 36);
        SelectLevel.add(lblSelectLevel);

        JLabel lblStart = new JLabel("Start");
        lblStart.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblStart.setBounds(186, 25, 61, 16);
        Start.add(lblStart);

        JButton btnHome_2 = new JButton("Home");
        btnHome_2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Home.setVisible(true);
                SelectKey.setVisible(false);
                SelectLevel.setVisible(false);
                Start.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        btnHome_2.setBounds(155, 216, 117, 29);
        Start.add(btnHome_2);

        JLabel lblSelectkeylabel = new JLabel("SelectKeyLabel");
        lblSelectkeylabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblSelectkeylabel.setBounds(175, 64, 97, 41);
        lblSelectkeylabel.setText(Integer.toString(key));
        Start.add(lblSelectkeylabel);

        JLabel lblSelectlevellabel = new JLabel("Selectlevellabel");
        lblSelectlevellabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblSelectlevellabel.setBounds(169, 107, 146, 41);
        lblSelectlevellabel.setText(Integer.toString(level));
        Start.add(lblSelectlevellabel);

        JLabel lblChoicedone = new JLabel("Choicedone");
        lblChoicedone.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.PLAIN, 16));
        lblChoicedone.setBounds(175, 147, 61, 16);

        if (key==0 || level ==0) {
            lblChoicedone.setText("Please go back and choose a key and a level");
        }
        else {
            lblChoicedone.setText("Please Start");
        }
        Start.add(lblChoicedone);

        JButton btnStart_1 = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart_1.setBounds(155, 185, 117, 29);
        Start.add(btnStart_1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so a couple of things you could start with.  Break down you "class" into seperate classes, each which becomes responsible for perform a single set task (such as allowing the user to select a level).  Then use a `CardLayout` to switch between them

Comment: Also, remember that Swing, like most UIs, is event driven, that is, something happens and then you respond to it.  It's not linear.  This means that when you code first runs, `lblSelectlevellabel` will pick up the initial value of `level`, but it is the never changed.  This is why I wold recommend following my previous comment